# Como esconder uma div de linha de tabela

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Boa tarde, tenho uma tabela onde mostro vários valores, mas tenho linhas onde por vezes não tenho numero e mostra N.A.

O que eu quero é apagar uma linha da tabela (`div id="ApagarNA"`) se todas as colunas dessa linha tiverem N.A.

No código estou a usar AngularJS, e já tentei usar `ng-if="!item.Last && !item.LastUm && !item.LastDois && !item.LastTres"` na div que quero apagar, mas ele apaga a linha mesmo se alguma coluna tiver numeros, e nao devia.

A tabela é esta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E está aqui uma parte do meu código que corresponde a mostrar uma das linhas. Para as restantes linhas o código é similar.

```
<!-- 2WK Type -->

<div id="ApagarNA" data-ng-if=$odd class="tableRowOdd" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS === '2WK'">
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextType" ><span>{{::item.TipoCalculado.split('#')[1]}}</span></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.Last"><span>{{::item.Last.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
          <h3 id="apagarcampo" id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.Last"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastUm"><span>{{::item.LastUm.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
          <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastUm"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastDois"><span>{{::item.LastDois.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
          <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastDois"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastTres"><span>{{::item.LastTres.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
          <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastTres"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="ApagarNA" data-ng-if=$even class="tableRowEven" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS === '2WK'">
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextType" ><span>{{::item.TipoCalculado.split('#')[1]}}</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.Last"><span>{{::item.Last.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
           <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.Last"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastUm"><span>{{::item.LastUm.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
           <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastUm"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastDois"><span>{{::item.LastDois.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
           <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastDois"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastTres"><span>{{::item.LastTres.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
           <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastTres"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
      </div>
</div>
```

Já tentei também com JavaScript, mas acontece o mesmo, apaga mesmo que uma das colunas tenha numero.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nove_meses = document.getElementById('ApagarNA');
    var h3s = document.querySelectorAll('#apagarcampo span');

    for(var i = 0; i < h3s.length; i++) {
        console.log(h3s[i].innerText);
        if(h3s[i].innerText == 'N.A.') {
            nove_meses.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Essa sua tabela está meio esquisita. Você está usando `AngularJS` puro?

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando repetições exaustivas de id's, o que é incorreto e complica na hora de usar JavaScript. A sugestão que eu poderia dar, a esse nível, era remover esses id's e trocar tudo por `class`.

O que você pode fazer para remover a linha é usar dois laços `for`, um aninhado em outro. O primeiro irá percorrer as divs principais selecionando pela classe. Como as classes começam com `tableRow`, você pode selecionar todas com o seletor `'div[class^=tableRow]'`.

O segundo `for` você irá percorrer todas as spans das divs com classe `.cellTextValueNA` verificando os seus textos.

Neste caso você pode verificar o inverso, se algum texto é diferente de `N.A.`. Caso seja, para o laço com `break` e parte pro próximo elemento. Após o segundo `for` você verifica se a variável `x` do `for` é igual ao tamanho do *nodelist*, se for igual, é porque todos os textos das spans da div percorrida é igual a `N.A.`, aí você esconde ela.

Veja um exemplo, onde no último `span` segunda div principal (de cor amarela) contém um valor `2`, e com isso ela não é ocultada:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^=tableRow]');

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){

   var h3s = divs[i].querySelectorAll('.cellTextValueNA span');

   for(var x = 0; x < h3s.length; x++){

      if(h3s[x].innerText != 'N.A.') break;
   
   }

   if(x == h3s.length) divs[i].style.display = 'none';

}
```

```css
.tableRowOdd{
   background: red;
}

.tableRowEven{
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="ApagarNA" data-ng-if=$odd class="tableRowOdd" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS === '2WK'">
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextType" ><span>{{::item.TipoCalculado.split('#')[1]}}</span></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.Last"><span>{{::item.Last.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
          <h3 id="apagarcampo" id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.Last"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastUm"><span>{{::item.LastUm.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
          <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastUm"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastDois"><span>{{::item.LastDois.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
          <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastDois"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tableCellContent20">
          <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastTres"><span>{{::item.LastTres.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
          <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastTres"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="ApagarNA" data-ng-if=$even class="tableRowEven" data-ng-show="item.TipoOWS === '2WK'">
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextType" ><span>{{::item.TipoCalculado.split('#')[1]}}</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.Last"><span>{{::item.Last.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
           <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.Last"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastUm"><span>{{::item.LastUm.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
           <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastUm"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastDois"><span>{{::item.LastDois.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
           <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastDois"><span>N.A.</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCellContent20">
           <h3 class="cellTextValue" data-ng-show="item.LastTres"><span>{{::item.LastTres.replace('.',',') | limitTo:7:0}}</span></h3>
           <h3 id="apagarcampo" class="cellTextValueNA" data-ng-show="!item.LastTres"><span>2</span></h3>
      </div>
</div>
```

> Não entendi a função desse `count = i++;`. Se puder explicar nos
>   comentários podemos inserir no lugar certo no código.

Comment: hello, I understand your solution, but it displayed none my entire table...